# В checkedListBox установка и снятие флажка при выделении элемента

Tags: c#, winforms

Научился ставить флажок при выделении элемента

```
private void checkedListBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = checkedListBox.SelectedIndex;
        checkedListBox.SetItemChecked(x, true);
    }
```

Но как сделать что бы при повторном выделении флажок снимался?

Comment: `checkedListBox.SetItemChecked(x, false);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может, так:

```
private void checkedListBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int x = checkedListBox.SelectedIndex;

    if(checkedListBox.CheckedIndices.Contains(x))
        checkedListBox.SetItemChecked(x, false);
    else
        checkedListBox.SetItemChecked(x, true);

    checkedListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

А еще проще вообще не обрабатывать событие MouseClick для checkedListBox, а установить

```
checkedListBox.CheckOnClick = true;
```

при инициализации формы (или в окне Properties элемента управления checkedListBox).